# Javascript regex to allow numbers and special characters like dot(.) and colon (:) for validating specific hostnames

Tags: javascript, regex, string, hostname

I have below host name and i want regex for the same

```
127.0.0.1:8181
```

The input contains numbers, dot(.) and colon (:)

I used below regex, but none of them worked

```
^([0-9]|#|+|*)+$
^[0-9*#+]+$
```

Adding my code snippet below

```
var guidRegex = new RegExp("/[0-9.:]+/")
var hostName = "127.0.0.1:8181";
var match = guidRegex.test(hostName);
```

After executing the value of match is **FALSE**

Comment: See for example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34438566/regex-pulling-ip-and-port-from-string or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2908740/java-regex-matching-ip-address-and-port-number-as-captured-groups or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23542035/how-to-modify-regular-expression-for-ipport

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
^\d+(?:\.\d+){3}(?::\d+)?$
```

### Demo

This will match an IPv4 address, along with an optional port number appearing at the end.

Answer (score 1):

To validate a string with `numbers . and :`.

```js
let str = '127.0.0.1:8181';
console.log(/[0-9.:]+/g.test(str));
```

To validate IPV4 ips addresses:

```js
let str = '127.0.0.1:8181';
console.log(/[0-9]{1,3}.[0-9]{1,3}.[0-9]{1,3}.[0-9]{1,3}:([0-9]+)?/g.test(str));

//OR

console.log(/^(?:[0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}(:[0-9]+)?$/g.test(str));
```

Comment: you mean the regex is just "/[0-9.:]+/"

Comment: yes, to validate a string with `number , . and : , but it will not validate ip adress, for taht you could use the second solution

Comment: I have updated my code above, and the regex which you gave is not working. Can you please let me know

Comment: Sure, let me check

Comment: You don't need to add `/` slash when creating with `new Regex()` . 

Try this. `new RegExp("[0-9.:]+")`

Comment: these are the syntax you can use. `new RegExp(/ab+c/, 'i') // literal notation`
 or `new RegExp('ab+c', 'i') // constructor`